# Custom authorization annotation with custom login page and how to to store the user?

Tags: asp.net

I want to create a custom Authorization annotation like this article
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/56fb14/custom-authorization-in-mvc/

But my question is how to redirect unauthorized/unauthenticated user to a specific login page and how to store the user information for the custom authorization?